# android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-multidex

I am not sure what this error means.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mygame"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }


dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
}
```